# Why (&HFFFF00 And &HFF00) = &HFFFF00?

Tags: excel, vba, hex

I was investigating a bug in a VBA function and I found out that `(&HFFFF00 And &HFF00) = &HFFFF00`.

I would expect for a different result: `(&HFFFF00 And &HFF00) = &HFF00`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

- The first value `&HFFFF00` is too large to fit in 16 bits, so it's automatically a Long
- The second value `&HFF00` does fit in 16 bits, so it's an Integer, that is a signed integer

Try to `Debug.Print &HFF00, &HFF00&` and you will see `-256  65280`. The first value is a signed integer, the second is forced to be a (signed) long by the `&` suffix.

Apparently VBA makes a mess by storing the values as 16 bit when possible, and butchering them when converting to 32 bits during the expression evaluation.

In order for the operations to work you need to force the constants to long by using the `&` suffix.

Answer (score 2):

It all stems from VBA's ability to make assumptions when you, the coder, don't fully specify what you want.

When you specify constant integer values in code *without* specifying the data type, VBA decides for you.  That decision is: if it fits in an `Integer` make it and `Integer`, else if it fits in a `Long`, make it a `Long`, else error.

When you do `A and B` and one of those is a `Long` and the other an `Integer` , the `Integer` is converted to `Long`.

In your specific example `&HFFFF00 And &HFF00` `&HFFFF00` is `Long`, and `&HFF00` is `Integer`, so `&HFF00` is converted to `Long` which is `&FFFFFF00` (note that the `Integer`  `&HFF00` is decimal `-256`, and so is `Long` `&FFFFFF00`)

After type conversion your equation is `&HFFFF00 And &HFFFFFF00` which equals `&HFFFF00`